# How to split chunks of xy data into lists between isalpha() and newline \n

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement

So I've got a cleaned up datafile of number strings, representing coordinates for polygons. I've had experience assigning one polygon's data in a datafile into a column and plotting it in numpy/matplotlib, but for this I have to plot multiple polygons from one datafile separated by headers. The data isn't evenly sized either; every header has several lines of data in two columns, but not the same amount of lines.

i.e. I've used `.readlines()` to go from:

```
# Title of the polygons
# a comment on the datasource
# A comment on polygon projection
Poly Two/a bit
(331222.6210000003, 672917.1531000007)
(331336.0946000004, 672911.7816000003)
(331488.4949000003, 672932.4191999994)
##etc

Poly One
[(331393.15660000034, 671982.1392999999), (331477.28839999996, 671959.8816), (331602.10170000046, 671926.8432999998), (331767.28160000034, 671894.7273999993), (331767.28529999964, 671894.7267000005), (##etc)]
```

to:

```
PolyOneandTwo
319547.04899999965,673790.8118999992
319553.2614000002,673762.4122000001
319583.4143000003,673608.7760000005
319623.6182000004,673600.1608000007
319685.3598999996,673600.1608000007
##etc

PolyTwoandabit
319135.9966000002,673961.9215999991
319139.7357999999,673918.9201999996
319223.0153000001,673611.6477000006
319254.6040000003,673478.1133999992
##etc etc

PolyOneHundredFifty
##etc
```

My code so far involves cleaning the original dataset up to make it like you see above;

```
data_easting=[]
data_northing=[]

County = open('counties.dat','r')

for line in County.readlines():

    if line.lstrip().startswith('#'):
        print ('Comment line ignored and leading whitespace removed')
        continue

    line = line.replace('/','and').replace(' ','').replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('),(','\n')
    line = line.strip('()\n')
    print (line)

    if line.isalpha():
        print ('Skipped header: '+ line)
        continue
```

I've been using `isalpha():` to ignore the headers for each polygon so far, and I was planning on using `if line == '\n': continue` and `line.split(',')` to ignore the newlines between data and begin splitting the Easting and Northing lists. I've already got the numpy and matplotlib section of the code (not shown) sorted to make 1 polygon, but I don't know how to implement it to plot multiple arrays/multiple polygons.

I realised early on though that if I tried to assign all the data to the 2 x and y lists, that would just make one large unending polygon that will make a spaghetti mess of my plot as imaginary lines will be drawn to connect them up.

I want to use the `isalpha()` section to instead identify and make a Dictionary or List of the polygon names, and attach an array for each polygon datablock to that, but I'm not sure of how to implement it (or if you even can). I'm also not certain how to make it stop loading data into a list at the end of a polygon datablock (maybe `if line == '\n': break`? but how to make it start and stop again 149 more times for each other chunk?).

To make it a bit more difficult, there is 150 polygons with x and y data in this file, so making 150 x and y lists for each individual polygon and writing specific code for each wouldn't be very efficient.

So, how do I basically do:

```
if line.isalpha():
    #(assign to a Counties dictionary or a list as PolyOne, PolyTwo,...PolyOneHundredFifty)
    #(a way of getting the data between the header and newline into a separate list)
    #(a way to relate that PolyOne Data list of x and y to the dictionary "PolyOne")

if line == '\n':
    #(break? continue?)
    #(then restart and repeat for PolyTwo,...PolyOneHundredFifty)

line.split (',')
data_easting.append(x) #x1,x2,...x150?
data_northing.append(y) #y1,y2,y150?)
```

Is there a way of doing what I intend? How would I go about that without pandas?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What format/data structure do you want these in ultimately? Also, is the delimiter always 2 newlines between polygons?

Comment: You might also want to include an example of the raw data before your *scrubbing*. Maybe the raw data can be *read into* the format you want without the intermediate step.

Comment: I want each data block to be in two numpy float arrays, x(easting) and y(northing). The delimiter is constant, always two newlines (\n\n). The headers aren't vitally important for the final plot, but I've just figured out how to get them into a dictionary so hopefully I'm on the final stretch of just making each data block into arrays and somehow assigning them to each Dictionary value. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: @wwii, I'll get a copy up now and update the question for you, but I think the point of the original datafile was to be cleaned up as it's all over the place.

Comment: Maybe add it too the bottom of the question with a [horizontal line](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#horizontal-rules) separating it. Along with where it comes from and whether there is a document explaining its format.

Comment: In your raw data example the first *block* has a different format than the second block. Do all subsequent blocks resemble the second block in your example?

Comment: No, most blocks are represented by the first example, but interspersed within the data are datablocks represented by the second example. With my code however I have all blocks regardless of format to be read into python 'cleanly'. Ideally that would mean I can `split` all the columns by `','`

Comment: @ggorlen, I miscounted, sorry, each datablock is separated by *one* newline.

Comment: Please post the raw actual text (truncated but representative) along with the desired output so there's no guesswork. The more indirection you introduce between the source and the desired result, the harder it's going to be to give you a good/relevant answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I've already posted representatives of  what I received to clean up and what I already have made progress with, I just need help appending it to 2 or more arrays correctly to plot it, or if I've approached it in the wrong way which could explain why I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the raw data/file:

When you encounter a line/block like the second in your example,

```
>>> s = '''[(331393.15660000034, 671982.1392999999), (331477.28839999996, 671959.8816), (331602.10170000046, 671926.8432999998), (331767.28160000034, 671894.7273999993), (331767.28529999964, 671894.7267000005)]'''
```

it can be converted directly to a 2d numpy array as follows using [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) which is a safe way to convert text to a python object - in this case a list of tuples.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import ast
>>> if s.startswith('['):
    #print(ast.literal_eval(s))
    array = np.array(ast.literal_eval(s))
    
>>> array
array([[331393.1566, 671982.1393],
       [331477.2884, 671959.8816],
       [331602.1017, 671926.8433],
       [331767.2816, 671894.7274],
       [331767.2853, 671894.7267]])
>>> array.shape
(5, 2)
```

---

For the blocks that resemble the first in your (raw) example accumulate each line as a tuple of floats in a list, when you reach the next block make an array of that list and *reset* it.  I put this all in a generator function which yields blocks as 2-d arrays.

```
import ast
import numpy as np

def parse(lines_read):
    data = []
    for line in lines_read:
        if line.startswith('#'):
            continue
        elif line.startswith('('):
            n,e = line[1:-2].split(',')
            data.append((float(n),float(e)))
        elif line.startswith('['):
            array = np.array(ast.literal_eval(line))
            yield array
        else:
            if data:
                array = np.array(data)
                data = []
                yield array
```

Used like this

```
>>> for block in parse(f.readlines()):
...    print(block)
...    print('*******************')

[[331222.621  672917.1531]
 [331336.0946 672911.7816]
 [331488.4949 672932.4192]]
*******************
[[331393.1566 671982.1393]
 [331477.2884 671959.8816]
 [331602.1017 671926.8433]
 [331767.2816 671894.7274]
 [331767.2853 671894.7267]]
*******************
>>>
```

---

If you need to *select* the northing or easting columns separately, consult the [Numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

---

Parsing with two regular expressions. This operates on the whole file read as a string: `s = fileobject.read()`. It needs to go over the file twice and does not preserve the block order.

```
import re, ast
import numpy as np

pattern1 = re.compile(r'(\n\([^)]+\))+')
pattern2 = re.compile(r'^\[[^]]+\]',flags=re.MULTILINE)

for m in pattern1.finditer(s):
    block = m.group().strip().split('\n')
    data = []
    for line in block:
        line = line[1:-1]
        n,e = map(float,line.split(','))
        data.append((n,e))
    print(np.array(data))
    print('****')

for m in pattern2.finditer(s):
    print(np.array(ast.literal_eval(m.group())))
    print('****')
```

Comment: That would help with those [] enclosed blocks, but wouldn't each block be overwritten by the next [] enclosed block if it relies on defining `array =`? I appreciate your response, but I'm still left with the main problem of appending all the blocks to plot together as independent polygons.